# Stop Playing Sound After Pressed Multi Times

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, media-player

I create an app with short sounds. And after I press button to play them, there is no problem

But in multi times press like 20 or more; app doesn't crash but stop playing sounds

I want to learn; how can I do an infinity working sound button ? Thanks

I write it onDestroy() but it doesn't work. Also I write it like that; but also it doesn't work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.x1);

    ImageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.release();
```

...

Comment: Please post the rest of your activity (at least the parts that deal with a MediaPlayer).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not calling `release()` on the `MediaPlayer` objects when you're done with them. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29):

> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call `release()`, to free the
>   resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.

Comment: Thanks @matiash I write also a release method but also it doesn't work on multiple pushing of button (like 25 times)    My code part ; protected void onDestroy() {
 
     super.onDestroy();
     
     mediaPlayer.release();
  mediaPlayer = null; }

Comment: @ISeeDeadPeople Don't release them in onDestroy(), release them as soon as you're done with them. Trust me, I'm sure this is the cause. :)